# Execution failing during :app:processDebugManifest gradle task in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, syntax-error

I have installed Android Studio and Gradle Plugin..... I tried to run my app but I'm getting the error message below:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] /root/.android/build-cache/493d9b2b1716da0abd8ebe85cfc268a98e65fd54/output/AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.v7.appcompat" to force usage
```

Comment: lets break it down... what do you understand from this msg: ***minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library***...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `minSdkVersion` is 10. `appcompat-v7` version `26.0.0-alpha1` no longer supports back that far; it only supports to API Level 14. Either:

- Raise your app's `minSdkVersion` to 14, or
- Stick with an older version of `appcompat-v7`, one that still supports a `minSdkVersion` of 10 or lower

Comment: I received a message from another user:

Comment: '
'
`dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1"
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.0.0'
}`
Where to write this code

Comment: @Abdelhamid you said you use `gradle`, right?

Comment: oohhh yes . use `gradle` ..... Thanks I was trouved a solution